# Find the top terms based off on TF-IDF scores across an entire column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf, textblob

I'm working on a script that will run through a column of article titles (read in from a .csv) in a data frame and calculate term frequency across the rows in this column using TF-IDF, list these terms with their TF-IDF values in a new df and then calculate an average share rate based on 2 other columns from the original data frame ((sum of all pageveiws for the articles where the keyword was found)/ (sum of all shares for the articles where the keyword was found) * 100).

Here is where I've reached:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from textblob import TextBlob, Word

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
dtm = vect.fit_transform(article_sentiment.title)
features = vect.get_feature_names()

word_scores = {}
for word in TextBlob(article_sentiment.title).words:
    word = word.lower()
    if word in features:
        word_scores[word] = dtm[features.index(word)]
```

But I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

UPDATE:

Here is some progress but I've generated another error:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from textblob import TextBlob, Word
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
dtm = vect.fit_transform(article_sentiment.title)
features = vect.get_feature_names()

article_titles = ' '.join(article_sentiment['title']).lower()

blob = TextBlob(article_titles).words

for word in blob:
    if word in features:
        word_scores[word] = dtm[features.index(word)]
scores = sorted(list(word_scores.items()), key=lambda x: x[1])

for word, score in scores:
    print(word, score)
```

The new error:

```
IndexError: row index (994) out of range
```

And an example of the data:

```
article_sentiment = {'title':['there’s always hope to be found','when women move forward, the world moves with them','a new collaboration to fight covid-19'], 'total_shares':[27, 53, 98], 'page_views':[2440.0, 5321.0, 4564.0]}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example so I can reproduce and debug on my machine? I.e. if you can provide a short example of what's in `article_sentiment` that'd be great

Comment: Sure thing - I'll drop an image on this thread of the first few rows of data.
I've also made some progress but am receiving another error so I'll share that too.

Comment: Rather than an image, if you could put your data into code, it'd be much better to work with! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks - I've added some in as a dict, let me know if that works?

Comment: Thanks for adding, but the code breaks because you're using `article_sentiment.title` which is not valid for the data you sent (try it yourself). I can't figure out what format the article_sentiment variable should be, so it's hard to know how to help!

Comment: Sorry, just changed the format following a tutorial. Is that better?